# android studio: get current gps location after drawing a path while moving

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

In this app I'm trying to :

- First draw a path between two final locations
- Then show GPS coordinates

The problem is when I execute the app stops but when I execute the part that draws the route alone it runs normally, the same thing with the GPS coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionFinderListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;


private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static String origin;
public static String destination;


private LocationManager locationManager;


private double latitude;
private double longitude;

private  LatLng latLng;


public static long mintime = 1000;//1000=1s
public static float mindis = 1;//1m



TextView  tvlat, tvlon, tvtem, tvdis;

float zoom = 16;
float tilt = 30;
float bearing = (float) 112.5;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    tvlat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlat);
    tvlon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlon);
    tvdis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdis);
    tvtem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtem);




    sendRequest(origin,desination);
    MyGPS();

}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;



    map.getUiSettings().isCompassEnabled();
    map.getUiSettings().isTiltGesturesEnabled();
    map.getUiSettings().isRotateGesturesEnabled();
    map.getUiSettings().isScrollGesturesEnabled();
    map.getUiSettings().isZoomControlsEnabled();
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(false);

    final LatLng firstLatLng = new LatLng(first.getLatitude(), first.getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(firstLatLng).title("start"));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng).zoom(zoom).tilt(tilt).bearing(bearing).build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


}

private void sendRequest(String origin, String destination) {

    try {
        new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Patientez SVP.",
            "Chargement..!", true);

    if (originMarkers != null) {
        for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    }

    if (destinationMarkers != null) {
        for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    }

    if (polylinePaths != null) {
        for (Polyline polyline : polylinePaths) {
            polyline.remove();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Route route : routes) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));

        tvtem.setText("Durée:" + route.duration.text);
        tvdis.setText("Distance:" + route.distance.text);

        originMarkers.add(map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                .title(route.startAddress)
                .position(route.startLocation)));
        destinationMarkers.add(map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                .title(route.endAddress)
                .position(route.endLocation)));

        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                geodesic(true).
                color(Color.CYAN).
                width(12);

        for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++) {
            polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));
        }


        polylinePaths.add(map.addPolyline(polylineOptions));

    }


}

public void MyGPS() {

locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

{

    return;
}

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if(location!=null)

{

    latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    onLocationChanged(location);
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,mintime,mindis,this);
 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latLng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

    longitude = location.getLatitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();

    tvlat.setText("Latitue:" + new DecimalFormat("##.###").format(latitude));
    tvlon.setText("Longitude:" + new DecimalFormat("##.###").format(longitude));


    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom), 2000, null);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    super.onBackPressed();

}

  }
```

this is the logcat :

```
  Line 28385: 05-25 09:41:20.746  2467  2477 I am_create_activity: [0,1146082216,60,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity,android.intent.action.MAIN,NULL,NULL,270532608,com.sec.android.app.launcher,0]
Line 28391: 05-25 09:41:20.766  2467  2991 I am_proc_start: [0,27907,10706,com.example.mimiryen.project,activity,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity]
Line 28391: 05-25 09:41:20.766  2467  2991 I am_proc_start: [0,27907,10706,com.example.mimiryen.project,activity,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity]
Line 28393: 05-25 09:41:20.801  2467  2478 I am_proc_bound: [0,27907,com.example.mimiryen.project]
Line 28394: 05-25 09:41:20.811  2467  2478 I am_restart_activity: [0,1146082216,60,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity,0]
Line 28397: 05-25 09:41:21.606 27907 27907 I am_on_resume_called: [0,com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity]
Line 28398: 05-25 09:41:21.851  2467  2592 I am_activity_launch_time: [0,1146082216,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity,1095,1095,1]
Line 28399: 05-25 09:41:21.941  2467  2467 I notification_cancel: [com.example.mimiryen.project,10436,NULL,0,0,64]
Line 28401: 05-25 09:41:22.256  2467  2995 I am_crash: [27907,0,com.example.mimiryen.project,13155908,java.lang.NullPointerException,NULL,NULL,-1]
Line 28402: 05-25 09:41:22.256  2467  2995 I am_finish_activity: [0,1146082216,60,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity,0,crashed]
Line 28403: 05-25 09:41:22.281  2467  2995 I am_pause_activity: [0,1146082216,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity,0]
Line 28415: 05-25 09:41:23.361  2467  2593 I am_destroy_activity: [0,1146082216,60,com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity,0,finish-imm]
Line 28416: 05-25 09:41:23.716  2467  2993 I am_proc_died: [0,27907,com.example.mimiryen.project,9]
Line 28422: 05-25 09:41:23.726  1952  1952 I sf_frame_dur: [com.example.mimiryen.project/com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity,6,2,2,2,0,0,0]
Line 28422: 05-25 09:41:23.726  1952  1952 I sf_frame_dur: [com.example.mimiryen.project/com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity,6,2,2,2,0,0,0]
Line 28424: 05-25 09:41:23.971  1952  1952 I sf_frame_dur: [Application Error: com.example.mimiryen.project,8,0,0,1,0,1,0]
Line 119144:   * Recent #6: TaskRecord{42576098 #60 A=com.example.mimiryen.project U=0 sz=0}
Line 119146:     affinity=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 119147:     intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity}
Line 119148:     realActivity=com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity
Line 122678:     Process com.example.mimiryen.project uid 10706: last crashed +17m48s891ms ago
Line 124751:     Package com.example.mimiryen.project:
Line 137127:         10: [2016-05-25 02:58:01.166] [Pid:(3131)]executeForChangedRowCount took 0ms - succeeded, sql="DELETE FROM logs WHERE ((((source_package = 'com.example.mimiryen.project'))) AND ((type = 4))) AND ( (logtype=500 OR logtype=800 OR logtype=100 OR logtype=120 OR logtype=510 OR logtype=900 OR logtype=110 OR logtype=1100 OR logtype=1000 OR (logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logtype=300 OR logtype=950))"
Line 137128:         11: [2016-05-25 02:58:01.166] [Pid:(3131)]prepare took 0ms - succeeded, sql="DELETE FROM logs WHERE ((((source_package = 'com.example.mimiryen.project'))) AND ((type = 4))) AND ( (logtype=500 OR logtype=800 OR logtype=100 OR logtype=120 OR logtype=510 OR logtype=900 OR logtype=110 OR logtype=1100 OR logtype=1000 OR (logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logtype=300 OR logtype=950))"
Line 137130:         13: [2016-05-25 02:58:01.162] [Pid:(3131)]executeForCursorWindow took 3ms - succeeded, sql="SELECT vvm_id FROM logs WHERE (((source_package = 'com.example.mimiryen.project'))) AND ((type = 4)) AND (logtype=500 OR logtype=800 OR logtype=100 OR logtype=120 OR logtype=510 OR logtype=900 OR logtype=110 OR logtype=1100 OR logtype=1000 OR (logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logtype=300 OR logtype=950) AND type = 4"
Line 137131:         14: [2016-05-25 02:58:01.161] [Pid:(3131)]prepare took 0ms - succeeded, sql="SELECT vvm_id FROM logs WHERE (((source_package = 'com.example.mimiryen.project'))) AND ((type = 4)) AND (logtype=500 OR logtype=800 OR logtype=100 OR logtype=120 OR logtype=510 OR logtype=900 OR logtype=110 OR logtype=1100 OR logtype=1000 OR (logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logtype=300 OR logtype=950) AND type = 4"
Line 150680:         43959eb8 com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity filter 43cb62b8
Line 150948:         43944a28 com.example.mimiryen.project/com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity filter 43ca9338
Line 154609:         43932da8 com.example.mimiryen.project/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver filter 43ca15a8
Line 167014:   com.example.mimiryen.project/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider:
Line 167015:     Provider{43887ef8 com.example.mimiryen.project/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider}
Line 167502:   [com.example.mimiryen.project.google_measurement_service]:
Line 167503:     Provider{43887ef8 com.example.mimiryen.project/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider}
Line 167504:       applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{442e7dd0 com.example.mimiryen.project}
Line 169361:   [com.example.mimiryen.project]
Line 179950:   Package [com.example.mimiryen.project] (44479588):
Line 179952:     pkg=Package{444a0e28 com.example.mimiryen.project}
Line 179953:     codePath=/data/app/com.example.mimiryen.project-7.apk
Line 179954:     resourcePath=/data/app/com.example.mimiryen.project-7.apk
Line 179955:     nativeLibraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.mimiryen.project-7
Line 179958:     applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{442e7dd0 com.example.mimiryen.project}
Line 179960:     dataDir=/data/data/com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 183823:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a704:
Line 184395:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a704:
Line 185291:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a704:
Line 185749:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a704:
Line 186917:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a705:
Line 187812:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a706:
Line 187863:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a705:
Line 188877:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a704:
Line 188878:       Process com.example.mimiryen.project (unique, 3 entries):
Line 188886:         myID=44cd45d0 mCommonProcess=44cd45d0 mPackage=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 188887:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a705:
Line 188888:       Process com.example.mimiryen.project (unique, 3 entries):
Line 188895:         myID=44ccfb18 mCommonProcess=44ccfb18 mPackage=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 188896:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a706:
Line 188897:       Process com.example.mimiryen.project (unique, 8 entries):
Line 188913:         myID=4499f948 mCommonProcess=4499f948 mPackage=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 198135:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a706:
Line 198205:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a705:
Line 198266:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a704:
Line 198995:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a706:
Line 198996:       Process com.example.mimiryen.project (unique, 2 entries):
Line 199000:         myID=443b1c90 mCommonProcess=443b1c90 mPackage=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 202718:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a706:
Line 203063:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a706:
Line 203064:       Process com.example.mimiryen.project (unique, 2 entries):
Line 203068:         myID=4398fb00 mCommonProcess=4398fb00 mPackage=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 207063:   * com.example.mimiryen.project / u0a706:
Line 209198: SpellScroll #154  name=com.example.mimiryen.project, targetPackage=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 209198: SpellScroll #154  name=com.example.mimiryen.project, targetPackage=com.example.mimiryen.project
Line 209200:   spellScrollComponent=com.example.mimiryen.project/com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity
Line 209200:   spellScrollComponent=com.example.mimiryen.project/com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity
Line 209208:       Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.mimiryen.project/.MainActivity }
Line 209568:   com.example.mimiryen.project: 20 times, 821458 ms
Line 209569:     com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity: 20 starts, 2000-3000ms=1, 3000-4000ms=2, 4000-5000ms=2, >=5000ms=4
Line 209676:   com.example.mimiryen.project: 10 times, 7506 ms
Line 209677:     com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity: 10 starts
Line 209769:   com.example.mimiryen.project: 26 times, 637650 ms
Line 209770:     com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity: 26 starts, 750-1000ms=1, 1000-1500ms=1, 1500-2000ms=2, 2000-3000ms=7, 3000-4000ms=3, >=5000ms=5
Line 209867:   com.example.mimiryen.project: 51 times, 1781435 ms
Line 209868:     com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity: 51 starts, 0-250ms=5, 250-500ms=5, 500-750ms=1, 750-1000ms=7, 1000-1500ms=4, 1500-2000ms=4, 2000-3000ms=3, 3000-4000ms=1
Line 209964:   com.example.mimiryen.project: 16 times, 584423 ms
Line 209965:     com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity: 16 starts, 750-1000ms=1, 1000-1500ms=4, 1500-2000ms=2, 2000-3000ms=3, 3000-4000ms=1, 4000-5000ms=1
Line 213532: pkgproc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10704,,0ne:1688232,1nt:108962,1ne:115963
Line 213533: pkgpss,com.example.mimiryen.project,10704,,0ne:4:25524:26098:26679:23124:23565:23964,1nt:2:26267:26731:27195:23552:24002:24452
Line 213534: pkgproc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10705,,0nt:596,1nt:359029,1ne:12049
Line 213535: pkgpss,com.example.mimiryen.project,10705,,1nt:5:18563:19668:20859:16052:17480:18428
Line 213536: pkgproc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,,0nt:390042,0ne:36604,0mt:162371,1nt:427884,1nl:1079,1na:5407,1ne:229728,1mt:4645
Line 213537: pkgpss,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,,0nt:6:21939:34286:37025:20420:32553:35216,0ne:1:22879:22879:22879:21444:21444:21444,0mt:2:22957:23005:23054:21448:21468:21488,1nt:7:20776:24143:35303:18672:22269:33596,1ne:2:19690:21285:22880:17964:19704:21444
Line 214981: proc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10704,0ne:1688232,1nt:108962,1ne:115963
Line 214982: pss,com.example.mimiryen.project,10704,0ne:4:25524:26098:26679:23124:23565:23964,1nt:2:26267:26731:27195:23552:24002:24452
Line 214983: proc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10705,0nt:596,1nt:359029,1ne:12049
Line 214984: pss,com.example.mimiryen.project,10705,1nt:5:18563:19668:20859:16052:17480:18428
Line 214985: proc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,0nt:390042,0ne:36604,0mt:162371,1nt:427884,1nl:1079,1na:5407,1ne:229728,1mt:4645
Line 214986: pss,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,0nt:6:21939:34286:37025:20420:32553:35216,0ne:1:22879:22879:22879:21444:21444:21444,0mt:2:22957:23005:23054:21448:21468:21488,1nt:7:20776:24143:35303:18672:22269:33596,1ne:2:19690:21285:22880:17964:19704:21444
Line 215411: pkgproc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,,1nt:2558,1ne:354
Line 216034: proc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,1nt:2558,1ne:354
Line 216275: pkgproc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,,1nt:2558,1ne:354
Line 216898: proc,com.example.mimiryen.project,10706,1nt:2558,1ne:354
Line 217106: P:com.example.mimiryen.project,20,821458
Line 217107: A:com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,4
Line 217214: P:com.example.mimiryen.project,10,7506
Line 217215: A:com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Line 217307: P:com.example.mimiryen.project,26,637650
Line 217308: A:com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity,26,0,0,0,1,1,2,7,3,0,5
Line 217405: P:com.example.mimiryen.project,51,1781435
Line 217406: A:com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity,51,5,5,1,7,4,4,3,1,0,0
Line 217502: P:com.example.mimiryen.project,16,584423
Line 217503: A:com.example.mimiryen.project.MainActivity,16,0,0,0,1,4,2,3,1,1,0
Line 219016:     Interval effective/min/max 5/5/5[s] Duration: 6[minutes] Client: WorkSource{10706 com.example.mimiryen.project} Tag: fused.NlpController:NlpFullPower LowPower: false Num requests: 15 Active: false
Line 219017:     Interval effective/min/max 5/5/5[s] Duration: 1[minutes] Client: WorkSource{10705 com.example.mimiryen.project} Tag: fused.NlpController:NlpFullPower LowPower: false Num requests: 3 Active: false
Line 219028:     Interval effective/min/max 30/30/30[s] Duration: 6[minutes] Client: WorkSource{10706 com.example.mimiryen.project} Tag: fused.NlpController:AR Num requests: 15 Active: false
Line 219029:     Interval effective/min/max 30/30/30[s] Duration: 1[minutes] Client: WorkSource{10705 com.example.mimiryen.project} Tag: fused.NlpController:AR Num requests: 3 Active: false
Line 219393:     Interval effective/min/max 5/5/5[s] Duration: 7[minutes] [com.example.mimiryen.project, PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY] Num requests: 17 Active: false
Line 219437:     05-25 09:41:23: Removed location request [10706:com.example.mimiryen.project]
Line 219442:     05-25 09:41:21: Added location request [10706:com.example.mimiryen.project]
```

Comment: place logcat for crash app

Comment: post your logcat....

Comment: check my edit @Abhishek Patel

Comment: check my edit @exception-lover